# how to train DeepLabv3+ on coco dataset with detectron

Tags: deeplab, detectron

I need to train DeepLabv3+ model on coco dataset. Detectron2 helped a lot when I trained it on cityscapes. Normally, detectron2 tells that when the config file is changed, you can train the model on other datasets. However, when I changed config file dataset section to coco, training process does not take place. Is there anyone who trained deeplabv3+ or deeplabv3 on coco dataset or how can I use the config file properly, what should I also change? When using detectron2, what should I pay attention in the config file?